# Assigning a new key to specific key-value pairs in a list of python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

*I have the following list of python dictionary:*

```
x=[{'a': '1',
   'b': '2',
   'c': '3',
   'd': '4',
   'e': '5',
   'f': '6',
   'g': '7'}]
```

*My desired output:*

```
   x=[{'g': '7', 'AA': {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6'}}]
```

I was able to assign a new key in the x list to specific key-value pairs, however, I'm appending it to the current list and getting the following output:

```
x=[{'a': '1',
   'b': '2',
   'c': '3',
   'd': '4',
   'e': '5',
   'f': '6',
   'AA':{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6'},
   {'g':'7'}]
```

Eventually, I had to remove the keys `a` through `f`.

*Current working solution:*

```
for k in x:
     k['AA'] = {u: k[u] for u in sorted(k.keys())[:6]}

rem_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
for k in rem_list:
    for v in x:
        v.pop(k)
```

I need to simply assign a new key to the corresponding key-value pairs on the fly without looping through the list twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a new dictionary? It's much safer as it doesn't manipulate mutable dict data, and may cause other methods using this dict to mis-behave.

Try something like:

```
x=[{'a': '1',
'b': '2',
'c': '3',
'd': '4',
'e': '5',
'f': '6',
'g': '7'}]

new_dict = {'AA': {k: v for k, v in x[0].items() if k != 'g'}, 'g': x[0]['g']}
```